# How to reset Windows XP password on Dell server with RAID?

Tags: windows-xp, raid, password, dell

I recently acquired a new customer that has an older Dell server running Windows XP (not sure if it is Home or Pro because I can't get into it).

I tried the usual start in Safe Mode and pray that the Admin user has no password, but it did.

So I found a Windows Password removal tool and was going to attempt that, but the problem is the OS is installed on a RAID logical drive which my bootable CD cannot see.

The RAID card is a standard Dell card (PERC or CERC...).

I need a solution on how to get this password reset so that we can access the OS.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a new recovery CD (BartPE) that has drivers for the RAID card.

- http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/

Or use the Linux-based password reset disks - those tend to have lots of drivers.

- http://pogostick.net/~pnh/ntpasswd/

Comment: Can you point me in the direction of one of these Linux-based password reset disks?

Comment: +1 for Bart PE, although it will need a password changing tool in addition to the drivers (plenty out there for those prepared to look).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest by far -- bypass local password authentication.

Download kon-boot (http://www.piotrbania.com/all/kon-boot/), burn it to CD or floppy, then boot to it. It will load up, then load Windows as normal. Once it boots, log on to Windows without entering a password. Or enter any password you want.

It actually changes the Windows kernel on boot to bypass authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Download Ubuntu here:

http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download

Once you've done that and burned it to a cd, boot the server and select the option to try Ubuntu without installing option. Then follow the instructions here:

http://www.ubuntu-unleashed.com/2008/04/howto-change-windows-administrator.html

Comment: Gotta love that article *"I absolutely hate microsoft products thats why I love breaking it. This hack, is way too easy. "* Someone should tell him that it's even easier to change the root password on Linux with physical access. If someone has physical access, there is always a way to get in.

Comment: haha yea, more detailed instructions if your a linux noob http://manoharbhattarai.wordpress.com/2010/03/31/remove-windows-password-using-chntpw-in-ubuntu/

Comment: Command needed seems to  be "Chntpw"

Answer (score 0):

Top two methods for you  to reset the lost windows password:

**Part 1** ： Using another available admin account to recover your windows password, however the methods for windows xp,vista and 7 password recovery ways are diverse from each other.

**Part 2:** Using windows password recovery tools to reset your forgotten login password

**Free one :  Ophcrack** and **Offline NT Password & Registry Editor**

**Charge one: Windows Password Unlocker**

Comment: +1 I am almost positive Ophcrack works with RAID

Comment: I am trying Orphcrack on a Dell 2950 with RAID, and it can't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Build an Ubuntu "Live CD" hopefully with your RAID controller enable, boot, now access the NT drives in the /media directory.  Then download and run "chntpwd":

[image: Change NT Password chntpwd]

See more instructions at https://www.top-password.com/blog/how-to-reset-windows-password-with-ubuntu-for-free/